# VST host - MIDI to wave conversion (C#)

Tags: c#, plugins, midi, wave, vst

I'd like to ask you for help with the VST host implementation.

Although wave processing had been quite easy to implement, I failed with the attempts of MIDI processing (in particular I need to convert MIDI events to wave output using my favorite plugin).

After reading the VST specification and various examples it seemed that the only difference between wave and MIDI plugins is just to call **ProcessEvents** before **ProcessReplacing** (with the correct timing).

Unfortunately, **ProcessEvents** fails with the memory access exception in my implementation and because I've verified the structures manytimes I decided to discuss it here :-)

Before I put here some piece of code, I will start the discussion with the essential question: what is the expected structure(s) of **ProcessEvents**.
This answer is important, because I've seen two approaches in the examples downloaded from another applications:

Most source codes use following memory layout:

```
[Int32 numEvents]
[reserved]
[IntPtr events] => [VstMidiEvent event1][VstMidiEvent event2]...[VstMidiEvent eventN]
```

*(where "events" points directly to one continuous block of **VstMidiEvent** structures)*

but I've also seen the implementation:

```
[Int32 numEvents]
[reserved]
[IntPtr events] =>
   [pointer to VstMidiEvent event1][pointer to VstMidiEvent event2]...[pointer to VstMidiEvent eventN]
```

*(where "events" points to block of pointers to **VstMidiEvent** structures and these pointers point to fragmented structures)*

Obviously one approach is wrong (I estimate the correct is the first one), but I've implemented both and both have the same behaviour: if only one event is present, **ProcessEvents** is called without any problem, but the wave buffer if always empty (no wave is generated) after following **ProcessReplacing** call. If more events are present, **ProcessEvents** crashes with memory protection fault.

I'll put here piece of code for further discussions, but first I'd like to know which memory layout is correct to focus just on the right approach.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Different event types have a different size, so the `VstEvents` structure contains an array of pointers to the events. Please note that `events` itself is not a pointer.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. So neither of above mentioned memory layouts is correct and if I understand it well, it shall be: `[Int32 numEvents][reserved][IntPtr event1ptr][IntPtr event2ptr]...[IntPtr eventNptr]`.

Comment: I have no clue how C#'s memory layout specification actually works, but this looks correct.

Comment: Look at VST.NET for 'inspiration'. http://vstnet.codeplex.com/ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses, the above mentioned solution `[Int32 numEvents][reserved][IntPtr event1ptr][IntPtr event2ptr]...[IntPtr eventNptr]` works fine :-)

Originally, it seemed I still had some implementation problem, because output from my instrument (**Universal Sound Module 2**) was just silence, but after deeper analysis I've found that all other instruments work fine and vice versa **Universal Sound Module** (which is bundled with **Cubase**/**Cubasis**) doesn't work with other DAWs (**LMMS**, **Cakewalk**, ...).

Does somebody have experience to get **USM2** working out of **Cubase**/**Cubasis**? The solution could be an implementation of "Vendor specific" callback - its occurence is the main difference from other instruments `(opcode = 35, index = 0, value = 0, ptr = {1301644}, opt = 2)`.

Although I'm quite sure that there is probably no solution, I'd appreciate if somebody has already solved it - there is no free replacement of high quality real instruments (just lots of synthesis implementations which are convenient for computer music, but not for rock, classical music, jazz, ...) and I don't want to buy other commercial instrument when I've already bought the **Universal Sound Module** and I "just" need to use it in different application.